# how to attach a function to a div without event handler (which is dynamically loaded)

Tags: jquery

i've a  which is square depending on width (did it with jquery).
it's working fine on preloaded div's
but how to make it work on dynamically loaded elemrnt?

html:

```
<button class="click">press to add a div</button>

<div class="square"></div>  <!-- working fine here caz it is preloaded on page load -->
<div class="container">
  <!-- container where div's will be added, and here square not working -->
</div>
```

js:

```
$(function(){

  $(".square").each(function(){
var width = $(this).outerWidth();
$(this).css("height",width+"px");
  });

  $(document).on("click" , ".click" , function(){
    // each square has different width
    $(".container").append("<div class='square'></div>");  // not working on this appended div
  });

});
```

elements which are dynamically loaded (into .container) are not working.
and there are no event to attach too in this case...

Comment: you can't do that... you will have to run the each loop code once again when the new `square` elements are created

Comment: @Satpal For delegating events, but that isn't the issue. The OP just needs to re-run a loop when the event is triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create a function, for example:

```
function calculate_widths()
{
  $(".square").each(function(){
   var width = $(this).outerWidth();
   $(this).css("height",width+"px");
  });
}
```

Then you execute this function whenever you want,

```
$(function(){

  calculate_widths();

  $(document).on("click" , ".click" , function(){
    // each square has different width
    $(".container").append("<div class='square'></div>"); 
    calculate_widths();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing that on document ready, you need to execute that while adding new squares -

create a function

```
function adjustWidth(){
 $(".square").each(function(){
   var width = $(this).outerWidth();
   $(this).css("height",width+"px");
 });
}
```

and then call it like this

```
$(function(){
  adjustWidth();
  $(document).on("click" , ".click" , function(){
    $(".container").append("<div class='square'></div>");
    adjustWidth(); // adjust width after adding new square
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).on("click" , ".click" , function(){
// each square has different width
  $(".container").append("<div class='square'></div>");
  var width =$(".container .square:last").outerWidth();
  $(".container .square:last").css("height",width+"px");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no delegated handlers for dom manipulation/widget initialization. You need to invoke those methods after the target elemetns are loaded to the dom

```
$(function () {
    function setHeight(els) {
        $(els).height(function () {
            return $(this).outerWidth();
        });
    }

    //if any square is there when page loads
    setHeight(".square");

    $(document).on("click", ".click", function () {
        // each square has different width
        var $div = $("<div class='square'></div>").appendTo(".container");
        setHeight($div)
    });

});
```